# Working with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Currently, I am attempting to format an NSDate string.

```
2013-08-25 22:54:00.500 MYSCHEDULER[23153:c07] 9:00 PM
2013-08-25 22:54:00.501 MYSCHEDULER[23153:c07] 2013-08-10 04:00:00 +0000
```

Here's the code I use:

```
- (NSString *)monthFormatter:(NSDate *)date
{
    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = nil;

    if (nil == dateFormat) {
        dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
    }

    return [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
}
```

What I would like to do is create a date formatter that takes out appending 0s.

So I have a time like `9:00 PM` and I would like to convert the time to `9 PM`. Is there a way this can be accomplished with a `NSDateFormatter`?

I attempted to do this : `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:m a"];` but it just made the date show up like so : `9:0 PM`

Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**

Also, I understand I could write:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h a"];
```

and that would satify this case but for the case of maybe `9:30 PM`, what would need to be done? Maybe a checker within the dateformatter method? But I figure Apple has already implemented this case.

Comment: Try this [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h a"];

Comment: haha I just made an edit for that... I just made it thinking about that case :P I think I just might have to make a checker to see if the date is 9:00 or 9:12 or 9:13... See if the time is on the hour or just past the hour, etc.

Comment: you are saying that if your time if 9.00 PM then it show 9 PM and if it is 9.12 PM thn its show as it is

Comment: yes exactly. im thinking i might have to come up with my own method to do this. like parse after the colon and delete the 2 zeros if its 9:00 pm then 'else' I wouldn't format

Comment: Read this link http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/ it shows all the format for the NSDate

Comment: there is no such type of formatter you have do this with logic

Comment: You will have to check for that yourself, and then choose your format string based on whether or not it falls exactly on the hour.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add like this, I hope it works :)

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH"];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want 9 PM as your answer give a below code try it works fine as per your need

```
NSString *time = [self monthFormatter:[NSDate date]];
NSArray *timeAMPM = [time componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSArray *hour = [time componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSLog(@"the time :%@ %@",[hour objectAtIndex:0],[timeAMPM objectAtIndex:1]);
```